# Timestamp consistency of dependent system-version tables

Tags: mysql, mariadb, data-versioning

I want to system-version some items that consists of data in forms of `blob`s as well as metadata.

I plan to use two tables, say `Metadata` and `Data`, to store them. `Data` has a `metadata_id` to refer to the metadata. (It could be the other way round actually, I am not sure which way around is more efficient in practice).

I want to make sure that when I query the history of the DB, I get a consistent DB. However that is not the case, because the timestamps that are present in `Data` and `Metadata` are not consistent, even when they are jointly filled within a transaction. (Sure, the time delta might be small, but I am looking for guaranteed perfect equality here).

How is this situation handled in practice? Should system versioning be used only on tables that do not need to be filled in a transaction along with other tables? Should I put my entries in a single row despite having large blobs? Should I implement my own versioning system?

Answer (score -1):

(Only addressing inconsistent timestamps)

```
SELECT @ts = UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
INSERT INTO     Data (..., ts, ...)  VALUES ( ..., @ts,  ...);
INSERT INTO MetaData (..., ts, ...)  VALUES ( ..., @ts,  ...);
```

Wrapping in a transaction does not matter *for getting the same `ts`*.

Comment: You cannot set the time stamp of a system-versioned table.

Comment: @user209974 - But does your task need system-versioned tables?

Comment: That's the crux of my question. System-versioning does exactly what I want, except it seems to require that tables are atomic in some sense. I could indeed implement my own custom versioning, but only if I need to. I am asking about how this situation is handled in practice by others who might have faced the same issue, and what led to their choice.